# Leaflet make PolyLine on top of geoJson

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I need to create dashed line on top of the geoJson object, but this object always appearing on top.

I have tried to set z-index parameters both to the css-classes of objects and as parameters in the js code, but it doesn't help.

I also see that the line moved to the top of geoJson when I manually drag the line's  tag below the countries  tag, but I surely don't want to do it in the js code with jquery (seems like a very bad decision).

I'm creating the map using this code:

```
// Creating the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([25, 10], 4);

// Creating the polyline
var pointA = new L.LatLng(-20, -20);
var pointB = new L.LatLng(80, 77.70641);
var pointList = [pointA, pointB];

var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
  smoothFactor: 1,
  className: 'my_polyline'
});
firstpolyline.addTo(map);


// Creating the geojson object
var geojson = {"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME": "Custom country" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [-0.18,29.76],[8.79,31.65],[13.54,27.61],[8.53,21.86] ] ] } }]}

var myCustomStyle = {
  stroke: false,
  fill: true,
  fillColor: 'green',
  fillOpacity: 1
}

L.geoJson(geojson, {
  clickable: true,
  style: myCustomStyle
}).setZIndex(1).addTo(map);
```

And some CSS:

```
.my_polyline { 
 stroke: red;
  fill: none;
  stroke-dasharray: 10,10; 
  stroke-width: 2;  
}
```

You can also see working example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d7v4bhku/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order you add them to the map matters. If you want the line on top, simply add it to the map after the `geojson` layer.

```
L.geoJson(geojson, {
  clickable: true,
  style: myCustomStyle
}).addTo(map);

var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
  smoothFactor: 1,
  className: 'my_polyline'
});
firstpolyline.addTo(map);
```

Then, you get your desired result.
[image: Dashed Polyline on top of GeoJSON]

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion about item ordering helped me to solve the issue.

However, I have tried to add the polyline at the end of the script before posting the question and it didn't work on my local machine (now I see that it works fine on jsfiddle, don't have any idea what is the difference, I'm using the same browser). 


So, to make sure, that the polyline will be added after the geojson, I have added a little bit of timeout (10ms) before adding the polyline, and now the issue is solved for my local machine too.